# How to get the first N elements in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django for-loop which is:

```
          {% for people in USPop %}
```

I would like to hand select the elements within the general dataset of USPop...e.g. like the first 3 elements or for just the 7-15 elements. How do I do that?

Note: I feel like the answer should be here, but I just couldn't find it...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `slice` filter on the page you linked.